# export object always {}

Tags: reactjs, npm

Recently i wrote a new package to publish to NPM, but when i package the `index.js` for package, i can not use it in other project.

the git address is https://github.com/ruoru/react-baidumap, u can download and use `npm install path/react-baidumap` in other project.

use `import { Point } from 'react-baidumap';` and it always return {};

any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json, main is pointing wrongly.

```
"main": "./docs/index.js",
```

it should point to `./src/index.js`. If you make this change and republish, I expect your import to work fine.

Comment: but i want package and ugly src code, can u have another way?

Comment: The uglified code folder should be lib preferably. Docs is bit confusing :) But did it work?